# Update PhpStorm desktop entry

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

I have updated my PhpStorm to 2017.2.4 (previously 2017.1.4).

To start 2017.2.4 I have to `cd phpstorm2.4folder/bin` then `./phpstorm.sh`

For 2017.1.4 I had a launcher icon, and now, if I click on this icon, it opens 2017.1.4.

How do I change the icon to launch the last update? I'm on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the old-folder did the job...